# Run jupyter nbextensions with an argument

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, autopep8

How can I pass `options={'max_line_length': 120}` to [jupyter-autopep8](https://github.com/kenkoooo/jupyter-autopep8)?

Here is the json defining library that I am trying to update.

```
{
    "python": {
        "library": "import json\nimport autopep8",
        "prefix": "print(json.dumps(autopep8.fix_code(u",
        "postfix": ")))"
    }
}
```

So that [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) will be called like

```
import autopep8
autopep8.fix_code('some_input', options={'max_line_length': 120})
```